# Communication between Rabbit Mq and Nodejs MicroService

Tags: node.js, docker, rabbitmq

I have a situation where I have to run 2 rabbitMq containers on docker, which are supposed to connect to 2 nodejs microservices. But i am stuck at a point where i m able to run 2 rabbitmq containers on docker on different port using: `docker run --hostname indoor-rabbitmq -d --expose 5672 -p 15672:15672 -p 5672:5672 --name indoor-rabbitmq $DOCKER_NAME`, because if i use `--net=host` i cannot run 2 containers on different port, handling independent requests. The issue is, i m not able to send request from rabbitmq container out of docker to the microservice running on localhost, neither am i able to login to `localhost:15672`. I m using `auth_cache.cached_backend" "http"` to login to rabbitmq, but i get `PLAIN authentication error: failed_connect, "localhost" "9085" econnrefused` error. `9085` is the port on which the authentication service is running. And `PLAIN authentication error: failed_connect, "localhost" "10085" econnrefused` error where 10085 is the port on which another authentication service is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a network in docker: `docker network create --subnet=172.18.0.0/16 mynet1`
`docker run -d --net mynet1 --ip 173.19.0.10 --hostname rabbitmq --add-host="localhost:192.168.0.21" -p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672 --name rabbitmq rabbitmq:3-management` and
`docker run -d --net mynet1 --ip 173.19.0.20 --hostname rabbitmq1 --add-host="localhost:192.168.0.21" -p 5673:5672 -p 15673:15672 --name rabbitmq1 rabbitmq:3-management` to be able to run 2 rabbitmq containers on docker.